# Python:Filter rows from Google SpreadSheet by Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, airflow

Requirement: To retrieve rows by date from Google Sheet, As the Google sheet can have data with the previous date

Example: I need to fetch only 11/9/2020

[image]

Currently, I am using Pandas to fetch all rows from Google Sheet, which was working fine, But have no idea how can I just fetch for the particular date filter from the google sheet

I have tried using the pandas' data frame query method to filter?

When I tried as below got an error

`df_query='Effective_Date=="2020-11-10"'`

`df = df.query(self.df_query)`

```
[2020-11-11 01:00:10,603] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - 'the label [Effective_Date=="2020-11-10"] is not in the [index]'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1506, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1501, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [Effective_Date=="2020-11-10"] is not in the [index]'
```

Comment: Can you please share the API for listQuery

Comment: You could just filter within the pandas frame if you already fetch it.

Comment: @PhilippJohannis Can you please help me with the error I am getting when using pandas data frame filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve by using Pandas Dataframe

`df_query='Effective_Date=="2020-11-10"'`

`df = df.query(self.df_query)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pandas data frame is called `df_query`, then the following should work:

```py
df_filtered = df_query[df_query['Effective_Date']=='2020-11-10']
```

Please provide `df_query.dtypes` and `df_query.head()` in case you still face errors.